# How to prove is Galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I want to prove $\Bbb C(x,y,z)/\Bbb C(x^2y,y^2z,zx^2)$ is Galois extension, and what is the extension degree.
I know $\Bbb C(x,y,z)/\Bbb C(x＋y＋z,xy＋yz＋zx,xy＋yz＋zx)$ is Galois extension with degree 6,

but I cannot solve the originl one because $x^2y,y^2z,zx^2$ is not symmetric expression.

P.S
How to show $\Bbb C(x,y,z)=\Bbb C(x,x^2y,y^2z,zx^2)$ ?
How can I make $y$ by $x,x^2y,y^2z,zx^2$?

And why is $T^9-x^9$ is minimal polynomial of $x∈ \Bbb C(x,y,z)$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3275811/11619). Use that to get started. Add the fruits of the resulting work to give a bit of context. You know the drill, I presume :-)

Comment: You can divide by things in a field!